# Notification cannot be cleared in Android

Tags: android

I want to create a notification that can be cleared.

e.g. Swipe right on ICS or by "Clear Notifications" button.

I can't figure this out and my notification cannot be cleared.

I tried it both on Froyo & ICS and I got the same issue.

My code is given below:

```
public class UploadPhotoService extends Service {

    private static final int SERVICE_ID = 999003;

  @Override
  public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {


    Notification note = new Notification(R.drawable.stat_notify_chat,
            "Uploading Photo", System.currentTimeMillis());

    String filePath = intent.getStringExtra("filePath");

    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(), 0);

    note.setLatestEventInfo(this, "Uploading Photo", filePath, pi);
    note.flags|=Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

    startForeground(SERVICE_ID, note);

    return(START_NOT_STICKY);
  }


  @Override
  public void onDestroy() {
    stop();
  }

  @Override
  public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return(null);
  }




  private void stop() {

      stopForeground(true);

  }
}
```

Comment: Are you getting notification with above code?

Comment: Sameer: Yes, The notification gets displayed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you are running a foreground service. Foreground service notifications stay up to alert users of a long running task. Drop the startForeground and it will work.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#startForeground(int,%20android.app.Notification)

If you want to show a notification just create one in the service, or on the correct events. Hope that helps.

Comment: Ah, that explains it. Makes sense.